# Dependent components with builtin data fetching

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Suppose I have a page with those React components:

```html
<CompetitionsPicker />
<SeasonsPicker />
<TeamsPicker />
```

Each of those component do some data fetching inside.

CompetitionsPicker provides a list of competitions. Competition.
SeasonsPicker provides a list of seasons, this depends on Competition. Seasons(competition)
TeamsPicker provides a list of teams, this depends on Competition and Season. Teams(competition, season).

Suppose that:

- I want to make the above component reusable from multiple pages.

How can I structure the above in such a way I end up with something like:

```html
<CompetitionsPicker /> // This modifies {competition} only
<SeasonsPicker competition={competition} /> This modifies {season} only
<TeamsPicker competition={competition} season={season} /> This modifies {team} only
```

I am having a hard time at coming up with something reusable. The above components are meant to be used by multiple pages (but some pages might use only two of the three above).

How can I structure the state for the above?

Comment: It seems to me like SeasonsPicker should be a child of CompetitionsPicker, and TeamsPicker a child of SeasonsPicker, given the dependencies. This could provide multiple benefits, including lazy loading based on selection within the parent component, without too much headache. This depends, though, on if SeasonsPicker should ever exist without a CompetitionsPicker. In that case, there most likely needs to be a further abstraction of dependencies into a layer that doesn't care about your presentation layer.

Comment: @BrandonMiller seasonsPicker might have to exist by itself, I have a case where competition might be hardcoded.

Comment: Without knowing the details any further, I'm not sure why it wouldn't be possible to create SeasonsPicker inside of the CompetitionPicker, even if it is hardcoded? If that does turn out to be the case, then I'd look into a couple of things. Firstly, try to make the components as generic as possible. I.E, can SeasonsPicker exist without a competition having ever been selected? If so, is it possible to encompass all competitions within a given season until a competition is selected? Otherwise, it may be best to hide these components from the DOM until all valid selections have been made.

Comment: (continued)... The second thing I'd look into is State management, such as redux. It's a great tool for situations like these, in which one component depends on another, but can't necessarily be directly childed to it, etc. By injecting application-level state into the dependant components you can achieve all of the above suggestions, and more. Pass the selected competition into state, which will then trigger SeasonsPicker, from SeasonsPicker, pass the selected season to state, etc. If redux is a bit too much, React has it's own API called "context" which works just as well in most cases.

Comment: Why don't you wrap all your components in a parent component and use some props to handle the visibility of all the 3 components inside? In that way, you can just use the parent component wherever you need and disable/hide one or more child components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I structure the above in such a way I end up with something
> like:
>
> ```
> <CompetitionsPicker /> // This modifies {competition} only
> <SeasonsPicker competition={competition} /> This modifies {season} only
> <TeamsPicker competition={competition} season={season} /> This modifies {team} only
> ```

Assuming you are using functional components style:

```
const [competition, setCompetition] = useState(null);
const [season, setSeason] = useState(null);
const [team, setTeam] = useState(null);
```

You need to add the `setX...` callbacks to each component's props, so that they can "return" the value selected.

For example, your `TeamsPicker` needs to take an extra prop (`onSelectTeam`), which it should call when a team is selected:

```
<TeamsPicker competition={competition} season={season} onSelectTeam={setTeam} />
```

Now to make sure that each component has all the data it needs in order to function correctly, you can either decide to conditionally render the components when all their props are ready, example:

```js
{<CompetitionsPicker onSelectCompetition={setCompetition} />}
{competition && <SeasonsPicker competition={competition} onSelectSeason={setSeason} />}
{(competition && season) && <TeamsPicker competition={competition} season={season} onSelectTeam={setTeam} />}
```

or have each component handle this condition by itself:

```js
{<CompetitionsPicker onSelectCompetition={setCompetition} />}
{<SeasonsPicker competition={competition} onSelectSeason={setSeason} />}
{<TeamsPicker competition={competition} season={season} onSelectTeam={setTeam} />}
```

Now each component decides what to display until all the props it needs are supplied with valid values.